# How to resize image using slider and resize property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using a jquery ui slider, and I want a user to be able to adjust the image size  with the resize property  using the slider.  What I'm not sure how to get it working. Any suggestions or ideas will be grateful.

```
  jQuery("#slider2").slider({
        value: 0,
        max: 360,
        min: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            jQuery(".resize-image").css({
              'resize': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
              '-moz-transform': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
              '-o-transform': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
              'transform': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
            })
   }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davadi/8dw0c4an/9/

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. `rotateZ` only, well, rotates, it doesn't have anything to do with resizing. Perhaps you're looking for `transform:scale()`? Could you make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick function to get the value of the slider and use that value to add or subtract from the width of the image.

```
$(function () {
var pre_val = 0;
$("#slider-range-min").click(function(){
    var val = $('#slider-range-min').slider("option", "value");

  var width_img = $(".bgSizeContain").width()
  if(val>pre_val){
    width_img += val
  } else {
    width_img -= val
 }
        pre_val = val;

$(".bgSizeContain").width(width_img)
    })
$("#slider-range-min").slider({change: function(event, ui) {console.log('It Works!')}});

});
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8dw0c4an/37/) to jsfiddle